# Magento 2 : Use HTTP i mistakenly set no

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, admin, cookie

In **`admin->stores->configuration->web->Default Cookie Settings->Use HTTP Only`**   i mistakenly set no after that in admin are blank how to solve this.

[image: a]

Comment: you remove `var/cache` and `var/view_processes` folder and run all commands

Answer (score 1):

You can change back the setting if you want through DB or CLI. Run following command

```
sudo php bin/magento config:set web/cookie/cookie_httponly 1
```

and clean cache. Let me know if you still face issue.

Comment: sir i try your command but still page are blank.

Comment: Have you ran cache clean too? If so please also run static content deploy using  sudo php bin/magento s:s:d

Comment: I run a command cache clean and deploy command but in console Error that css is Blocked. https://prnt.sc/tpr1dn

Comment: This is happening as the site maybe using https and the static content is being server using http.

Comment: sir how to solve this

Comment: check under admin->stores->cofiguration->web->base urls if "Base URL for Static View Files" is using https

Comment: Yes its using https. https://prnt.sc/tprdef

Comment: both media and static file urls are empty in the screenshot, please populate them.

Comment: Sir how to done Secure URLs in Admin put yes by commandline in magento2

Comment: pls help me to sove this issue

Comment: sir on page inspect put css url from http to https is working fine. pls help me to done all css and js  from http to https.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111134/discussion-between-vivek-kumar-and-naeem-dhattiwala).